# include Forking - Multi threading in bash script to run it in upstart?

Tags: bash, init-script, upstart

I have lack of understanding. Do i need to include forking in my bash script: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/26756839/4749164**, so i can use `expect daemon/fork` - option in `upstart`?

i would like to run my bash script as process in background through upstart, so far i did:

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown or runlevel [12345]

respawn
expect daemon

script
  export HOME="/user"
  echo $$ > /var/run/bashscript.pid
  exec /etc/rfid/bashscript
end script

pre-start script
   echo "[`date`]" program starting >> /var/log/bashscript.log
end script

pre-stop script
   rm /var/run/program.pid
   echo "[`date`]" program stopping >> /var/log/bashscript.log
end script
```

when i run in terminal: `sudo service bashscript status`
it says that `bashscript` is running and it has Pid which is true if i check: `/var/run/bashscript.pid` But there is no such process running in `top` with that pid and if i type in terminal:
`sudo service bashscript stop` it hangs. What am i doing wrong or missing?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: For start i would like to run my bash script as service - process. After that i would like to know what needs to be done to achieve subprocessing..

Comment: Likely the problem lies in `/etc/rfid/bashscript` and it's exiting abnormally.

Comment: Can you please explain what were you thinking with that? bashscript has no extension because its executable and there is no need to include `exec bash -c` because my bashscript has shebang at beginnig of code, so i don't think that's the problem... or am i wrong?

Comment: Depends - does it sit in a loop and keep running, and is the environment at boot time when it's called appropriate for it to 'work'?

Comment: while system boots it has no problem but if i want to restart or shutdown, it hangs because it is waiting termination of that process. Most likely because that process has no pid associated even if it was created... and i don't know how to solve that...